# No operator needed for assignment in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I've been trying to learn Ruby, and I recently reoccuringly saw something like this in a few people's Github repo:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/ubuntu-15.04-snappy-core-edge-amd64"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest:80, host:8080
end
```

Why is there no assignment operator after config.vm.network? Is this non-standard Ruby? Or are they passing arguments in a function? What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your guess is correct. The `config.vm` object has a `network` method. The Ruby syntax is pretty relaxed, but this call can be written more "formally" like

```
config.vm.network("forwarded_port", {guest: 80, host: 8080})
```

This relaxed form that you are seeing often is a common convention. (Hence why you are seeing it quite often!)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You're passing arguments in a function.  See [here](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/b420da067812be9feb3cfab07680ab4dcff66bed/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm.rb#L230).